# Automate correct spacing after ! in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros, math-operators

[image]

```
$(2n)!/\bigl(n!\,(n+1)!\bigr)$
$${52!\over13!\,13!\,26!} + 33!! - y$$
$(2n)!/\bigl(n!(n+1)!\bigr)$
$${52!\over13!13!26!} + 33!! - y$$\bye
```

How could we automate the spacing after `!`? As explained in the TeXBook, `!` requires manual handling of spacing after it. I would like to see what ideas do you have that would lead to correct spacing (first two lines) with input similar to the usual (last two lines).

I added the case of `!!` which should have no space in between, the rest is from the TeXBook. It's a plainTeX because of that, but any solution would be nice.

Answer (score 5):

You can try the macro `\mathexclam`:

```
\def\mathexclam{\futurelet\next\mathexclamA}
\def\mathexclamA{%
   \expandafter\ifx\space\next
      \def\next{\afterassignment\mathexclam\let\next= }\expandafter\next
   \else \edef\tmpb{\meaning\next}\let\tmpa=\mathpunct
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mathexclamB\expandafter\tmpb\string\mathchar\end
      \iftrue \expandafter\mathexclamC\tmpb\end
      \else \mathexclamD !+-*/=<>,.)]\}\bigr\biggr\Bigr\Biggr\right\over\egroup$\relax
      \fi
      \tmpa{\mathchar`!}%
      \ifx\tmpa\mathpunct \mathchoice{}{}{\,}{\,}\fi
   \fi
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\mathexclamB\expandafter#\expandafter1\string\mathchar#2\end#3{%
   \ifx^#1^%
}
\def\mathexclamC#1"#2#3\end{%
   \ifnum#2=1 \let\tmpa=\mathord \fi % Big OP
   \ifnum#2=2 \let\tmpa=\mathord \fi % Bin
   \ifnum#2=3 \let\tmpa=\mathord \fi % Rel
   \ifnum#2=5 \let\tmpa=\mathord \fi % Close
   \ifnum#2=6 \let\tmpa=\mathord \fi % Punct
}
\def\mathexclamD#1{\ifx#1\relax \else
   \ifx#1\next \let\tmpa=\mathord\fi
   \expandafter\mathexclamD \fi
}
{\catcode`!=13 \global\let!=\mathexclam} \mathcode`!="8000

$(2n)!/\bigl(n!(n+1)!\bigr)$, $1\over 2!3!$.
$${52!\over13!13!26!} + 33!! - y$$
\bye
```

This macro first ignores the spaces after `!`. The spaces are non-significant in math mode. Then the `\mathexclamB` does a test if the next token is deflared as `\mathchardef` (for example `\le`). If it is true then `\mathexclamC` is processed. Else the explicit list of exceptions is processed by `\mathexclamD`. The `!` is typeset as `\mathpunct` by defualt. But if the next token is Op, Bin, Rel Close or Punct (declared by `\mathchadef`) then `!` is typeset as `\mathord`. Moreover, if next token is one from the list of exceptions used after `\mathexclamD` then `!` is typeset as `mathord` too.

Comment: Nice. Note, however, that `\mathpunct` doesn't add the thin space in scriptstyle, so the output in `$1\over 2!3!$` will not be as expected. So probably the macros should add `\,` explicitly when needed, not relying on `\mathpunct`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a little code in order to tread spaces in scriptstyle. But I know that the macro cannot be universal or general. There are many exceptions...

Comment: Yes, my impression is that it's easier to remember adding `\,` when typing. The thirteen kinds of atoms are not really sufficient for completely automatic typesetting. There should be a **Factorial** atom for this application and also a **Slash** atom for the fraction slash, rather than considering it an ordinary atom.

Comment: This is acceptable nice, in this case it's not about *remembering adding `\,`* but *implementing this correct spacing* in an already written two hundred pages document. Besides it would be nice to have it automated. @egreg That last comment of yours, since it's not possible to “create new atoms” with TeX macros, would it be possible to implement a new system based on a `\count` which each math symbol sets to a number, and then the next one adds certain space based on the value of that `\count`?

Comment: @Manuel The problem is that you can't know what follows until the math list is fully built. How many expansion steps will you perform? What if you have `\newcommand\npi{(n+1)}` and `\npi` is buried in another macro?